# SQL Server query with update error from select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
update ItinventoryR1 
set iin_userid = (select emp.empid 
                  from employee emp, itinventoryr1 it 
                  where ltrim(rtrim(it.iin_username)) in (emp.empname))
```

Error is :

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need something like this:

```
UPDATE R1
SET iin_userid = emp.empid
FROM itinventoryr1 R1
INNER JOIN employee emp
    ON ltrim(rtrim(R1.iin_username)) = emp.empname
```

Join tables, and update one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
update t1 
set t1.iin_userid =t2.emp_id
from ItinventoryR1 as t1 inner join employee emp as t2
on ltrim(rtrim(t1.iin_username))=t2.empname
```